# Bootstrap dropdown menu does not collapse in angularjs spa application

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

i am using bootstrap LTR 3.1.1 in an angularjs SPA project. i am using this code to create dropdown menu in my application:

[bootstarp dropdown menu example](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#make-navbars-accessible)

but when i click on **dropdown** link Submenus wont appear and my app will redirect to its root directory.

how can i resolve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We had a similar problem on a project with angular + bootstrap where dropdown elements would redirect to root. We changed the

`<a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>`

into

`<a href="javascript:;" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>`

The `href="#"` is indeed referring to the root of your app, removing that and replacing it with that removes the link while maintaining the pointer cursor. Alternatively, you could add a CSS class like

```
.pointerCursor {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

and replace the `<a>` tag with a `<span>` tag and append the class to the new span element.

Comment: thank you ... it was useful for me .....another solution is using angular-strap or using ui-router or angular-ui but your suggest was short and easy .... :)